# jQuery dynamically showing popup without static HTML property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, properties, triggers

I have a popup modal error message which gets triggered when I add a property to an html tag like following:

```
  <button class="btn btn-alt4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod-error" >Cancel Me</button>
```

Please note the following property of this button:

```
data-target="#mod-error"
```

When I add this property, whenever I click on the button, the modal error message pops up and shows on the screen...

I would like to trigger this modal to show on this button, but dynamically via jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-alt4",function()
{
 // trigger the modal here
});
```

I have tried doing something like:

```
$("#mod-error").trigger("click");
```

But this doesn't do anything ...

How can I achieve this via jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.modal("open")` function of bootstrap to open the modal

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-alt4",function()
{
 $("#mod-error").modal("open");
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply ! =) Which library do I have to reference in order to use this modal() method?

Comment: Right now I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: f[b] is not a function

Comment: i assume you are using bootstrap,are you not?

Comment: yes I'm, but for some reason i'm getting that error =/

Comment: does the modal open, what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Erm, it doesn't opens up, it just shows this error in console

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: that one for some reason =(

Comment: the version of bootstrap is 4

Comment: I'm wondering if theres another way to solve this without calling bootstraps method

Comment: ivescu $("#mod-error").toggle("open"); did open it up, but it looks weird and it doesnt responds at all xD

Comment: Hey madalin, $("#mod-error").modal(); did the trick, just without "open" inside the modal method :)

Comment: strange.., but glad to have helped

Comment: Yes it really is strange... Btw. just accepted your answer =)